# Retrieve attribute values as shader will see them?

Tags: opengl, shader

I have vertex and fragment shaders written for WebGL that are working fine.  I am trying to get them to work in a C++ program using OpenGL 2.1.  (Why 2.1? Because this is an old project, and I'm gradually trying to update it. On a Mac I think that's what's available in compatibility mode.)

So far it appears the vertex shader is working, but if I enable lighting the triangles appear black, when they should be multicolored.  If I turn lighting off, they are displayed properly, so the fragment shader is doing something, just not the right thing for lighting.  This makes me suspect that the normals aren't being handled properly.

Is there a way to query OpenGL 2.1 to see what values it is sending to the shader for a particular attribute on each vertex?  I can use `glGetVertexAttribfv()` to find the various characteristics of the attribute, but I'm worried that I'm not interpreting them the same way as OpenGL does.

Comment: Use a GPU debugger like Nsight or RenderDoc? Or just draw the normals as color?

Comment: Suggestions: map the values to a color and render them, or use RenderDoc. " If I turn lighting off" makes it sound like you're mixing the fixed-pipeline with modern OpenGL, which doesn't work.

Comment: @BDL:  drawing them as color still shows black, so I think that confirms I am not setting them properly.  Now I just need to figure out where that is going wrong.  The setting is very similar to the way I'm setting the position vector.

Comment: @Yun:  no, I'm pretty sure I'm not mixing the pipelines here, though it's possible I've missed something.  I've just got a shader with lots of defines, and when I said "turn the lighting off" I'm changing a define so the lighting calculations are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Comments from @BDL and @Yun answered my question.  There isn't a simple way in OpenGL 2.1 to see values being passed to the shader, but modifying the shader to assign the normals to the output color made it clear that the normals were being sent incorrectly.  (They also suggested debuggers Nsight and RenderDoc, but I didn't need to try those yet.)

It turned out that the program was calling `glBufferData()` to send the data to the buffer before adding the normal data on the client side.  This meant the shader was being told to get the normals from beyond the end of the buffer, and it got zeros for everything.  I'm a little surprised this didn't trigger an OpenGL error, but it's easy to fix.